# Can the Massachussets State House be [CLEARED]?

Tags: fallout-4

I have visited this location quite a while ago. Killed the Mirelurk Queen down below, killed the female raider with a minigun up top. The place didn't receive the [CLEARED] marker then. Now I visited it again trying to determine if it bears any relation to the Freedom Trail quest, and imagine my surprise when I realized the place got reset, pretty much. I have again fought the Queen and killed the minigun-wielding raider. And, again, I can't get it [CLEARED]. Is that possible to do? Am I missing something?

Comment: just checking, but have you killed the raider commander who is wearing power armor?  If not then you haven't cleared it yet ;)

Comment: @z: that's covered in my question ;) I have killed her TWICE by now.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that it doesn't clear and resets from time to time because you need the queen's meat for a specific recipe.

Comment: Although CLEARED areas should still reset, but just takes much longer.

Comment: Odd. Is that related to some quest? Even if it is, I don't understand why the reset isn't tied to me taking the quest.

Comment: If you already cleared something before you got a quest you should get an option saying you already did it like taking the FC in the museum of freedom or clearing out Pikman's Gallery for a quest Hancock gives you before he's your follower.

Comment: Violet, if you are referring the recipe I was talking about, it's not related to quests, it's an item you need to cook up a great meal. If you haven't tried it already I would suggest you do because the buffs you get from some of those meals are seriously over powered and they make the game much much easier at harder difficulties (also you get exp for the cooking).